# How to find the probability density function for a function's values?

Tags: probability, statistics, descriptive-statistics

If I have a function $f(x)$ with a domain $[a,b]$ and range $[c,d]$, how do I find the moments of the values the function attains in the domain?

More importantly, how do I find the PDF for the function's values?

I'm motivated by a problem Functional Integration. I can find both the mean value of a functional $S[f]$ and the standard deviation. However, I'd like to find the PDF for the values the functional attains.

For $f(x)=x$ on $[a,b]$, I can make an educated guess and state the PDF is $\rho(f(x))=\cfrac{1}{b-a}$.

But I don't really know what the PDF looks like for even moderately more complex examples like $f(x)=x^2$ or $f(x)=\cos(x)$.

(I'll take references/links; but an example is always appreciated)

Comment: If $f$ is strictly increasing, continuous, and $f(b)=d$, then the situation is straightforward: if $X$ is uniform on $[a,b]$ and $y \in [c,d]$ then $P(f(X) \leq y)=\frac{f^{-1}(y)-a}{b-a}$. With a little extra work you can deal with any monotone $f$. But if $f$ is not monotone then the situation can become quite complicated, since you basically have to find all solutions to the equation $f(x)=y$ for every $y$.

Comment: @Ian True, and interesting btw, but I really do want a PDF.

Comment: What I said furnishes a PDF if $f^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable (or more generally absolutely continuous). But there is no nice formula for what to do except in the monotone case.

Comment: @Ian True, if you have a link or anything feel free to post it.